# How do I create public variables after the class has been instantiated?

Tags: vb.net

Using Winforms and VS 2012:

I need to create a new class of items, but when the class is created, I won't know how many items I will need. Only after it has been created and sized will I know how many I need. So can I create more after the class has been instantiated?

For example:

I am creating a panel and in that panel I will have some child panels. However I don't know how many children. It will be based on how tall the parent panel is.

```
Public Class parent_panel()

   Public panel_1 as new panel

   Public Sub New()

     with panel_1
       .parent = Me
       .location = new point(0,0)
     end with

   End Sub

End Class

Public Class main()

   Private p_panel as new parent_panel

   Public Sub new()

     with p_panel
       .parent = Main
       .location = new point(0,0)
       .width = Main.width
       .height = Main.height
     end with
     ' now that I know the height of this panel, I need to go back and add
 '"panel_2", "panel_3" and so on to parent_panel until I fill the height of this panel.

      End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You can have a member of parent_panel which is a List(of Panel).

Comment: How exactly would I do that? When would that be created? and how would I add more to the list and have them be publicly available?

Comment: Try a `TableLayoutPanel`

Comment: Thanks, but a TableLayoutPanel will not work for what I need. I need a very specific way of handling the panel and its objects.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, you wouldn't use discrete variables for each child because you can't add variables after compilation.  You would use one variable to store a single object that can then contain multiple objects, i.e. an array or collection.  If the size will be set once and remain the same then you should use an array but if it may change then you should use a collection, i.e. a `List(Of Panel)`.